# How to register ECS Cluster with Opsworks Stack in CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-opsworks, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I can't figure out how to setup an OpsWorks Layer using an ECS Cluster in CloudFormation. My Layer creation fails because of the error below but there doesn't seem to be a clear way to register the cluster with the stack in the template. I tried adding `EcsClusterArn` to both Stack and Layer but that did not work. The API has a command for it but I'd like to contain everything in my template.

Error:

```
Attributes - EcsClusterArn: XXX must be registered to the layer's stack first.
```

Snippet of template:

```
"ecsCluster" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::ECS::Cluster"
},
...
"opsworksStack" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::OpsWorks::Stack",
  "Properties" : {
    "Name" : "my-stack",
    "ServiceRoleArn" : {
      "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "arn:aws:iam::", {
        "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId"
      }, ":role/", {
        "Ref" : "ServiceRole"
      } ] ]
    },
    "DefaultInstanceProfileArn" : {
      "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "arn:aws:iam::", {
        "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId"
      }, ":instance-profile/", {
        "Ref" : "InstanceRole"
      } ] ]
    },
    "UseOpsworksSecurityGroups" : "false",
    "ChefConfiguration" : {
      "BerkshelfVersion" : "3.3.0",
      "ManageBerkshelf" : "true"
    },
    "ConfigurationManager" : {
      "Name" : "Chef",
      "Version" : "11.10"
    }
  }
},
"opsworksLayer" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::OpsWorks::Layer",
  "DependsOn" : "ecsCluster",
  "Properties" : {
    "StackId" : {
      "Ref" : "opsworksStack"
    },
    "Type" : "ecs-cluster",
    "Name" : "my-layer",
    "Shortname" : "my-layer",
    "Attributes" : {
      "EcsClusterArn" : {
        "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "arn:aws:ecs:", {
          "Ref" : "AWS::Region"
        }, ":", {
          "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId"
        }, ":cluster/", {
          "Ref" : "ecsCluster"
        } ] ]
      }
    },
    "CustomSecurityGroupIds" : [ {
      "Ref" : "ec2DefaultSecurityGroup"
    } ],
    "EnableAutoHealing" : "true",
    "AutoAssignElasticIps" : "false",
    "AutoAssignPublicIps" : "false",
    "InstallUpdatesOnBoot" : "true"
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Thien

Comment: Hi Thien, I am just wondering if you were able to resolve this issue? I am also facing same error while attaching a ECS cluster to an Opsworks stack.

Comment: @ManishJoshi I had created a case with Amazon and they had resolved the bug on Feb 24, 2016. It should be working now using "EcsClusterArn" in the "Attributes" section for the OpsWorks Layer as described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Thien , Unfortunately it is still not working for me, I have raised  case with Amazon, they are still looking into it. I'll let people here know if I find some other reason for this error too :)

Answer (score 2):

My impression is that the registration of the cluster to the stack fails. To work around this, i have implemented a lambda function to do the registration manually. I have posted an example template on github: https://github.com/arjenderijke/aws-cloud-examples/blob/master/cloudformation/opsworks/opsworks-ecs-layer.template

The cloudformation template contains a full example of an opsworks stack with an ecs layer and the other minimal required resources. The stack would normally fail to create, because the ecs cluster is not automatically registered. To work around this, the template implements a custom resource that runs an aws lambda function. This function registers the cluster to the stack. By using this custom resource, the error no longer occurs.

```
 "OpsworksRegisterCluster": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Handler": "index.lambda_handler",
    "Role": { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["LambdaExecutionRole", "Arn"] },
    "Code": {
      "ZipFile":  { "Fn::Join": ["\n", [
        "import boto3",
        "import json",
        "import cfnresponse",
        "ecsclient = boto3.client('ecs')",
        "opsworksclient = boto3.client('opsworks',",
        "  region_name='us-east-1',",
        "  endpoint_url='https://opsworks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com')",
        "def lambda_handler(event, context):",
        "  try:",
        "    if (event['RequestType'] == 'Create'):",
        "      ecscluster = ecsclient.describe_clusters(clusters=[",
        "        event['ResourceProperties']['EcsClusterName']])",
        "      response = opsworksclient.register_ecs_cluster(",
        "        EcsClusterArn=ecscluster['clusters'][0]['clusterArn'],",
        "        StackId=event['ResourceProperties']['OpsworksStackId']",
        "      )",
        "      responseData = {}",
        "      responseData['data'] = response['EcsClusterArn']",
        "      cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS,   responseData, \"CustomResourcePhysicalID\")",
        "    else:",
        "      responseData = {}",
        "      cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData, \"CustomResourcePhysicalID\")",
        "  except Exception as e:",
        "    responseData = {}",
        "    responseData['error'] = e.message",
        "    cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.FAILED, responseData, \"CustomResourcePhysicalID\")"
      ]]}
    },
    "Runtime": "python2.7",
    "Timeout": "10"
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for everyone's knowledge, I was facing this problem with AWS cloudformation a couple of days back and I raised a case with Amazon for this.

It seems this problem still exists in their API (As pointed by Thien in the comments this bug was supposed to be resolved in Feb 2016) and it hasn't been resolved, not sure it is because I am using nested stacks that this problem exists(Maybe in a single template it is not the case, I haven't tried that).

AWS people have asked me to use the lambda function to resolve this issue and it is very similar lambda function as provided by @Arjen above. So if you are facing this issue please use the lambda function provided above.

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 0):

According to section [Adding an ECS Cluster Layer to a Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinglayers-ecscluster.html#workinglayers-ecscluster-add), *Associating a cluster with a stack requires two operations*:

> [...] registering the cluster with the stack and then creating the associated layer. **The AWS OpsWorks console combines these steps**; layer creation automatically registers the specified cluster. **If you use the AWS OpsWorks API, CLI, or SDK, you must use separate operations to register the cluster and create the associated layer**. *[emphasis mine]*

You state that you *tried adding `EcsClusterArn` to both Stack and Layer but that did not work*, but the error message confirms that the [Amazon ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ecs/) cluster *must be registered to the layer's stack first*, and your sample template is missing this aspect in fact? In case, you might simply need to repeat your resp. fragment from `AWS::OpsWorks::Layer` within `AWS::OpsWorks::Stack` too:

```
   "Attributes" : {
      "EcsClusterArn" : {
        "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "arn:aws:ecs:", {
          "Ref" : "AWS::Region"
        }, ":", {
          "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId"
        }, ":cluster/", {
          "Ref" : "ecsCluster"
        } ] ]
      }
    },
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I had tried before but removed it from what I posted. I just double-checked and it still gives me the same error.